# how to edit .htpasswd using php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have a protected directory where only user on .htpasswd can access, but sometimes it requires the user to change password or username, edit a specific username password to his username him self

```
sample users
kevien : kka
mike : mike
```

And let say i want to change kevien to XYZ

And same thing goes to password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofc this is just a sample, that will read your current file, find the given username and change either it is password of username.

**Please keep in mind that this code is not safe and you would still need to parse the username and password so it does not break your file.**

```
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $new_username = $_POST['newuser'];
    $new_password = $_POST['newpass'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    //read the file into an array
    $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('.htpasswd'));

    //read the array and change the data if found
    $new_file = "";
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$line); // remove spaces
        if ($line) {
            list($user, $pass) = split(":", $line, 2);
            if ($user == $username) {
                if ($action == "password") {
                    $new_file .= $user.':'.$new_password."\n";
                } else {
                    $new_file .= $new_username.':'.$pass."\n";
                }
            } else {
                $new_file .= $user.':'.$pass."\n";
            }
        }
    }

    //save the information
    $f=fopen(".htpasswd","w") or die("couldn't open the file");
    fwrite($f,$new_file);
    fclose($f);
```

Comment: Does this code really work correct? Doesn´t it say "if the user stored in the file does not match the user given by the input than add the user plus password to the file"?

Comment: If user does not match with one already in the file it will change nothing and it says at the top `Ofc this is just a sample` means its untested, but the logic is there and you can always make a test file and test your self.

Answer (score 11):

I have modified function to use all types of crypt alghoritms. Someone may find it useful:

```
/*
Function change password in htpasswd.
Arguments:
$user    > User name we want to change password to.
$newpass > New password
$type    > Type of cryptogrphy: DES, SHA, MD5. 
$salt    > Option: Add your custom salt (hashing string). 
           Salt is applied to DES and MD5 and must be in range 0-9A-Za-z
$oldpass > Option: Add more security, user must known old password to change it. 
           This option is not supported for DES and MD5 without salt!!!
$path    > Path to .htaccess file which contain the password protection. 
           Path to password file is obtained from this .htaccess file. 
*/  

function changePass($user, $newpass, $type="SHA", $salt="", $oldpass="", $path=".htaccess")
{
    switch ($type) {
        case "DES" :
            $salt = substr($salt,0,2);  // Salt must be 2 char range 0-9A-Za-z
            $newpass = crypt($newpass,$salt);
            if ($oldpass != null) {
                $oldpass = crypt($oldpass,$salt);
            }
            break;

        case "SHA" :
            $newpass = '{SHA}'.base64_encode(sha1($newpass, TRUE));
            if ($oldpass != null) {
                $oldpass = '{SHA}'.base64_encode(sha1($oldpass, TRUE));
            }
            break;

        case "MD5" :
            $salt = substr($salt,0,8);  //Salt must be max 8 char range 0-9A-Za-z
            $newpass = crypt_apr1_md5($newpass, $salt);
            if ($oldpass != null) {
                $oldpass = crypt_apr1_md5($oldpass, $salt);
            }
            break;

        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    $hta_arr = explode("\n", file_get_contents($path));

    foreach ($hta_arr as $line) {
        $line = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$line); // remove spaces
        if ($line) {
            $line_arr = explode('"', $line);
            if (strcmp($line_arr[0],"AuthUserFile") == 0) {
                $path_htaccess = $line_arr[1];
            }   
        }
    }  
    $htp_arr = explode("\n", file_get_contents($path_htaccess));

    $new_file = "";
    foreach ($htp_arr as $line) {
        $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line); // remove spaces
        if ($line) {
            list($usr, $pass) = explode(":", $line, 2);
            if (strcmp($user, $usr) == 0) {
                if ($oldpass != null) {
                    if ($oldpass == $pass) {
                        $new_file .= $user.':'.$newpass."\n";
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $new_file .= $user.':'.$newpass."\n";
                }
            } else {
                $new_file .= $user.':'.$pass."\n";
            }
        }
    }
    $f = fopen($path_htaccess,"w") or die("couldn't open the file");
    fwrite($f, $new_file);
    fclose($f);
    return true;
}
```

Function for generating Apache like MD5:

```
/**
 * @param string $password
 * @param string|null $salt
 * @ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786956
 */
function crypt_apr1_md5($password, $salt = null)
{
    if (!$salt) {
        $salt = substr(base_convert(bin2hex(random_bytes(6)), 16, 36), 1, 8);
    }
    $len = strlen($password);

    $text = $password . '$apr1$' . $salt;

    $bin = pack("H32", md5($password . $salt . $password));

    for ($i = $len; $i > 0; $i -= 16) {
        $text .= substr($bin, 0, min(16, $i));
    }

    for ($i = $len; $i > 0; $i >>= 1) {
        $text .= ($i & 1) ? chr(0) : $password[0];
    }

    $bin = pack("H32", md5($text));

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $new = ($i & 1) ? $password : $bin;

        if ($i % 3) {
            $new .= $salt;
        }

        if ($i % 7) {
            $new .= $password;
        }

        $new .= ($i & 1) ? $bin : $password;
        $bin = pack("H32", md5($new));
    }

    $tmp = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $k = $i + 6;
        $j = $i + 12;

        if ($j == 16) {
            $j = 5;
        }

        $tmp = $bin[$i] . $bin[$k] . $bin[$j] . $tmp;
    }

    $tmp = chr(0) . chr(0) . $bin[11] . $tmp;
    $tmp = strtr(
        strrev(substr(base64_encode($tmp), 2)),
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
        "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    );

    return "$" . "apr1" . "$" . $salt . "$" . $tmp;
}
```

Demo of `crypt_apr1_md5()` is available [here](https://3v4l.org/89YpT).

Note that [as of Apache 2.4, **bcrypt** is supported](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html), so you can (and SHOULD) just use `password_hash()` on newer versions of Apache for this purpose.

Comment: The code is very good, just one suggestion that to put $tmp = ""; before: for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { //so that undefined notice message does not occur.

Comment: I've updated the code to enhance readability, and to point out that bcrypt is supported as of Apache 2.4. Just use bcrypt, you'll be much happier.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Store your authdb in a database instead, via e.g. mod_auth_mysql.

Comment: Vazquez-Abrams do you have any tutorials on how to implement it

Answer (score 3):

Googled "php generate htpasswd", got this article: [How to create a password for a .htpasswd file using PHP](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/).

The key line seems to be:

```
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));
```

So I imagine you'd read in the file contents with `file_get_contents`, parse it into an associative array, modify the relevant entries (encrypting the password as shown above), write the array back into a string, and use `file_put_contents` to write the file back out.

This is most definitely not standard practice, however. Sounds like the job for a database. If you feel weird about setting up a whole database server, and your host supports it, [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) might be a good choice.

Comment: i found a fully functional class but the problem with it is that if the user exist it doesn't over write it, it adds another line, there i well be having the same user but multiple passwords 
`http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4178.html`

Comment: @Mahmoud - how interesting. I wish you luck in either modifying the code to fit your needs, or writing your own solution.

Comment: i am only using there idea, not the code itself, i want to create a solutions but i am stuck after encoding the password, is it possible to search and overriding the text

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is just looking for a working script, here is a solution.

It is the script published here by Kavoir with a minor change: http://www.kavoir.com/backyard/showthread.php?28-Use-PHP-to-generate-edit-and-update-htpasswd-and-htgroup-authentication-files

```
<?php
/*
 $pairs = array(
  'username' = 'password',
 );
*/

// Algorithm: SHA1

class Htpasswd {

private $file = '';

public function __construct($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $this -> file = $file;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function write($pairs = array()) {
    $str = '';
    foreach ($pairs as $username => $password) {
        $str .= "$username:{SHA}$password\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($this -> file, $str);
}

private function read() {
    $pairs = array();
    $fh = fopen($this -> file, 'r');
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $pair_str = str_replace("\n", '', fgets($fh));
        $pair_array = explode(':{SHA}', $pair_str);
        if (count($pair_array) == 2) {
            $pairs[$pair_array[0]] = $pair_array[1];
        }
    }
    return $pairs;
}

public function addUser($username = '', $clear_password = '') {
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($clear_password)) {
        $all = $this -> read();
      //  if (!array_key_exists($username, $all)) {
            $all[$username] = $this -> getHash($clear_password);
            $this -> write($all);
     //   }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function deleteUser($username = '') {
    $all = $this -> read();
    if (array_key_exists($username, $all)) {
        unset($all[$username]);
        $this -> write($all);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function doesUserExist($username = '') {
    $all = $this -> read();
    if (array_key_exists($username, $all)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function getHash($clear_password = '') {
    if (!empty($clear_password)) {
        return base64_encode(sha1($clear_password, true));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

You can use this script like:

```
$htp = new Htpasswd('.htpasswd');
$htp -> addUser('username1', 'clearpassword1');  // this will add or edit the user
$htp -> deleteUser('username1');  
// check if a certain username exists
if ($htp -> doesUserExist('username1')) {
 // user exists
}
```