# HTPASSWD Automatic

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

quick question. I setup a timecard and PO system for a family business. The employees enter their username and password to enter the system. Every time the family hired someone though they send me the info. I use htpasswd generator, and open the file up, add it, and then re-upload use ftp. My wife enter's their info into the db using a php page i setup though and i'm wondering if there is a way to allow her a txt field that can she can copy and past the generated pw into the htpasswd file. Without having me to always change it.

To summarize: is there a form command that when i put in the txt field and push submit it automatically puts the txt into the htpasswd file

Comment: Thanks Nirk for the edit! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a php page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994637/how-to-edit-htpasswd-using-php) has an example of the code you need:

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$new_username = $_POST['newuser'];
$new_password = $_POST['newpass'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
//read the file into an array
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('.htpasswd'));

//read the array and change the data if found
$new_file = "";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $line = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$line); // remove spaces
    if ($line) {
        list($user, $pass) = split(":", $line, 2);
        if ($user == $username) {
            if ($action == "password") {
                $new_file .= $user.':'.$new_password."\n";
            } else {
                $new_file .= $new_username.':'.$pass."\n";
            }
        } else {
            $new_file .= $user.':'.$pass."\n";
        }
    }
}

//save the information
$f=fopen(".htpasswd","w") or die("couldn't open the file");
fwrite($f,$new_file);
fclose($f);
```

Here is also a [slightly more complete solution](http://www.innvo.com/c/PHP/1311865299-htpasswd-manager). Or just look it up on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=php+update+htpasswd+file&oq=php+update+htpa).